# How can I see the verbatim contents of a shell variable?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I want to view the verbatim contents of a shell variable on Debian containing terminal escape codes. If I try to `echo` its contents, then all of the terminal escape gets interpreted by the terminal to e.g. display colours.

```
➜  sds git:(master) echo $PS1
%(?:%{%}➜ :%{%}➜ ) %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)
```

Is it possible to print the verbatim contents of a shell variable, or do I need to find the exact script that sets it in order to view its verbatim contents?

Comment: Is that really what you see when you `echo $PS1`? Why are there unexpanded variables in the output?

Comment: That’s looks like a Zsh prompt. `$` in a shell variable isn’t expanded when the variable itself is expanded: `test='$hello'; echo $test`.

Comment: @StephenKitt  - yes, it's Zsh prompt I'm referring to in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) [says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620639/86440), you can’t get back the original construction of the variable if it was constructed using the values of other variables.

However you can see its contents, uninterpreted by the terminal or even by the shell itself, in at least Bash and Zsh:

```
printf '%q\n' "$PS1"
```

This will escape all the characters which would otherwise have a different effect; you can use this to reconstruct the verbatim contents.

Another approach is to output the variable’s contents to somewhere other than the terminal (directly); for example

```
printf %s "$PS1" | od -vtc
```

will show the variable’s contents, character by character, replacing control characters with a mnemonic (`nl`, `esc`, `sp`...).

Do *not* use `echo` here which expands `\x` sequences and adds an extra newline character.

In your case,

```
%(?:%{%}➜ :%{%}➜ ) %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)
```

looks like it could be exactly the verbatim contents of your `PS1` variable: there are no terminal-interpreted escapes there, those are indirectly obtained through the `fg` array and `reset_color` variable. Assuming the `promptsubst` option is set, those would be expanded when `PS1` is used to display the prompt, but not when `echo $PS1` is expanded.

Comment: But none of your approaches will show `$variable`, they will instead show the expanded variable's contents. For example, if you construct a PS1 like this: `var="foo";  PS1="$var \$"`, then `printf '%q\n' $PS1` will just show `foo\n\$` and not `$var\n\$`. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I say in my first paragraph, effectively. In your example, `PS1` is assigned the value of `var` followed by a space and an escaped `$`; displaying it can only show that. In the question, the `$` symbols are unexpanded in the variable definition.

Comment: @terdon, to complement Stephen's comment above, the OP probably has the `promptsubst` option enabled which causes those `$var` to be expanded at the time of *prompt* expansion (but not in `echo -E - "$PS1"` not upon *parameter* expansion)

Comment: In `zsh`, to see the result of prompt expansion, you can do `print -rP - $PS1`.

Comment: @terdon - Sorry, if I haven't made it explicit enough, but I don't care about expanded variables. What I care about are terminal escapes that are interpreted by the terminal, when I use e.g. `echo` to display the variable's contents.

Answer (score 4):

The contents of the variable include the expanded values of any variables you are using. You cannot get back to the original because the original is only used to expand the values.

For example, consider this:

```
fooVar="foo"
barVar="$fooVar : bar"
```

By the time the shell sets `barVar`, it has already expanded `$foovar`. It isn't setting `barVar` to `$fooVar : bar`, it is setting it to `foo : bar`. There is no way of getting back to `"$fooVar : bar"`, the `$vooVar` variable was expanded before being assigned as a value to the new `barVar` variable. That's the whole point of using variables, after all: that they can be treated as their value.

So no, there is no way of getting the genie back in the bottle and "unexpanding" variables you have already expanded and used. The only way to see what variables were used to form your `PS1` is to track down the various files where it is being set.

Comment: It's conceivable that you could write a script which analyzes your entire `env` and comes up with suggestions on how certain vars could be used in templates for other vars ... but it seems like a lot of work for little benefit.

Comment: @RossPresser I doubt it. For one thing, there's no reason to assume that a variable used in the definition of another will still be set and present in your env. Maybe it was only ever defined within one file that was executed to set one variable.